# Is there a shorter way to move a ui element in iOS?

Tags: ios, uikit

I find myself doing this a lot:

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, otherView.frame.origin.y + otherView.frame.size.height + 10, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height);
```

Obviously a lot of this code is repeated. I'm only moving the element down, but I have to create a new CGRect since I can't access the attributes directly.

Is there an easier way of moving elements around at runtime that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

Not a completely different way, but a more comfortable one if you ask me:

```
CGRect newRect = webView.frame;
newRect.origin.y = otherView.frame.size.height+10;
webView.frame = newRect;
```

I find this to be way more readable as well. In this particular example, it's about 40% less characters! :p

Answer (score 2):

```
view.frame = CGRectOffset(view.frame, 5, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Will CGRectOffset help?

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/ipad/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

@wasabii has the correct answer as far as reducing the amount of code, but another approach to consider is creating a category on UIView.  Here are some docs about categories: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html

Basically a category allows you to add functionality to a class that you don't control (or even one you do control).

Xcode 4.2 provides a template for creating a category under the new file dialog, so use that if you can.

In this case you might create a category on UIView with a method called

```
-(void)moveDownByIncrement:(float)increment
```

Then implement the movement code however you like (but really use @wasabii's method).

A few things to keep in mind about categories:

1. They affect the class itself, so when you add a method to a category it is available app wide.
2. You'll get an error (or warning depending on your project setup) when you try to call a category method if you have not imported your category header (import it either in class or in preprocessing).
3. Categories are defined with a namespace, which can cause a collision.  The best way to avoid this is to prefix any methods you add (and the category name itself) with a project specific prefix.  Many third party libraries and open source projects use a category on NSData called - (NSString *)base64EncodedString, so save yourself the headache and give that method a prefix in your own category.
4. Setting properties or ivars on a category is troublesome at best and deserves a discussion on it's own.  If you don't know how to do that just don't try it!